# Polkit Window doesn't allow user selection, how to pick different admin

Tags: sudo, users, administration, policykit

I'm running the latest Ubuntu 20.04.1
It seems like polkit(I could be wrong here) isn't working as expected.   When a regular, non-admin, user tries to do something that needs admin, they get a dialog asking for the password of a specific user on the system (lets say user1).  Even though user1, user2, and user3 are all in the sudo group on the system.  It only shows user1 .

How do I set it up so we can pick from the users in the system with sudo/admin privileges when getting the authentication dialog?

We are getting this dialog when trying to install software through the GUI or add networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to choose the admin account because the current GNOME Shell built-in polkit authentication agent just pick the first one if it gets more than one. It seems that nobody in the GNOME community has ever considered the possibility to use GNOME in a corporate environment with more than one administrator account.

You can find the details of the current implementation here, at line 46: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/components/polkitAgent.js

Comment: Thanks.  This is the feeling I got.  I moved to creating custom polkit configurations per system, so the correct user was selected.